# Disable Guest User from Terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, guest-account

After updating from Monterey to Ventura (M1 chip), a guest user account is now showing as the only login option with a password that I do not know - there is no option to switch user (although in recovery mode my user profile is still there). I’ve tried reinstalling Ventura which didn’t work. Upon my 10th time of going into recovery mode I was prompted to reinstall Monterey - when selecting this the macbook told me that I cannot downgrade the software on the disk. As there is no Time Machine backup, my only option now it seems is to somehow disable the guest user from the terminal. I’ve googled around for how to do this and have found nothing helpful. If possible, can someone here tell me exactly what needs to be I texted in the terminal (using -bash) to disable the guest user or better yet force the computer to start in my admin profile?

Comment: This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) The guest account is not the issue, the loss of your main account is the issue. BTW, the guest account doesn't have a password, it's available to anyone, but it is extremely limited in functionality. It should always be enabled, as it is used in part of FindMy, in case the Mac is ever lost or stolen.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @V_Smith?